# Shift lever and boss (mount point) compatibility matrix

Tags: shifter, compatibility, downtube-shifter

I've looked online, but haven't found one. Is there any sort of "matrix" available that puts shift lever *boss* type on one axis and shift *lever* on the other, and remarks on each pair's compatibility?

Ideally, this would include bosses that include the following (and any others that might be useful): downtube braze on, downtube clamped on, barend "pods", "thumbie pods", stem-mounted.

Each type on each axis would be collapsed based on same-shape/same-size with some notes on which specific items fall into each type category.  So, something like this:

```
      Bosses:
             Shimano d/t "A"    Campagnolo d/t "A"    Paul Thumbies    ....
Levers:    ======================================================================
Shimano   |                   |                     |               |
  333     |                   |                     |               |
          |----------------------------------------------------------------------
Campagnolo|                   |                     |               |
SR "A"    |                   |                     |               |
          |----------------------------------------------------------------------
Simplex   |                   |                     |               |
   "A"    |                   |                     |               |
          |----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ...    | ...

Bosses:
Shimano d/t "A": PICTURE.  DESCRIPTION.   DIMENSIONS.  IDENTIFYING CHARACTERISTICS. ETC.
Campagnolo d/t "A": PICTURE.  DESCRIPTION.   DIMENSIONS.  IDENTIFYING CHARACTERISTICS. ETC.
...
Levers:
Simplex "A": etc. etc.
...
```

Comment: As far as I know shift lever bosses are one of the few things that are actually fairly standard across all manufacturers.

Comment: @FredtheMagicWonderDog, That's a help, for sure. Do you happen to know about between manufacturer compatibility? That would be alright if all types in the requested matrix are simply categorized by manufacturer.

Comment: I have always been able to use anything on anything, but I haven't used everything. Campy shift levers from the mid 60's fit on modern downtube bosses and vice versa. I'm sure there is a counter example somewhere, but I've never run into it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its a poor fit for a Q&A site.